# Complex differentiation and Fréchet differentiation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb{C}$ and define $H:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: x+iy\in G\}$.

Let $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function.

Define $u(x,y)=Re(f(x+iy))$ and $v(x,y)=Im(f(x+iy))$ for all $(x,y)\in H$.

Assume $f$ is differentiable at $x+iy$.

Then, is it true that $u$,$v$ are Fréchet-differentiable at $(x,y)$?
(This is a yes/no question)

In most complex analysis text, it is only stated that $u,v$ has partial derivatives and since in almost all case we are given $C^1$ function, it is not really necessary to state that $u,v$ are Fréchet-differentiable. However, I have proven it and I want to make it clear.

I have proven it in the following way:

Define $g(x,y)=f(x+iy)$.

Then, it is direct that $g$ is Fréchet-differentiable at $(x,y)$ and $Dg(x,y)(a,b)= f'(x+iy)(a+ib)$.

So set $T=Re\circ Dg(x,y)$ and $S=Im\circ Dg(x,y)$. Then, it is again direct to show that $T,S$ are Fréchet-derivatives of $u,v$ respectively.

Comment: Just use the $f(z + h) - f(z) - f'(z)h = o(|h|)$ characterization of differentiable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is complex differentiable if and only if both $u$ and $v$ are Frechet differentiable and they satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations. This fact is interesting, but in practice not that relevant. Note that complex differentiable implies $\mathcal C ^{\infty}$, and in particular $\mathcal C^1$. This means that Cauchy Riemann equations imply that Frechet differntiability is equivalent to $\mathcal C ^{k}$ for every $k$ including $\infty$. So in practice you only need to check if function is $\mathcal C^1$ and satisfies C-R eqns., without loss of generality.

Edit: I extended my answer

Another edit:

First note that $\mathbb C$ can be identified with set of $2\times 2$ matrices of the form:

$a+ib= \begin{bmatrix}a & - b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$

You can easily check that this is an isomorphism. Now as you know, Frechet derivative at a point is a linear operator. You can identify it with a matrix:

$f'=\begin{bmatrix}u_x & u_y \\ v_x & v_y \end{bmatrix}$

With subscript denoting partial derivative. Condition of complex differentiability at a point means that this operator exists and that it can be identified with multiplication by complex number. By comparing this matrix with general matrix form of complex number you get precisely Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thank you. But the I think the point is that this is about differentiability at a point, not a domain.

Comment: Oh, I need to think about it a little more. I don't remember right now if it is possible to have function which is complex differentiable at a point but not in any of its neighbourhoods.

Comment: Alright.. Then please verify this and tell me later. I will accept it again then :) thank you

Comment: Sorry but the matrix 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a & - b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}
$$
is *not* skew-symmetric, unless the elements of the diagonal are individually zero, right ?

Comment: You are right. These matrices are not skew-symmetric - I made a mistake. On the other hand it is true that matrices of this form are characterized by the property that they commute with the matrix $J=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, which corresponds to the imaginary unit.